# Extend object on Meteor

Tags: meteor

When i add/edit blogPost, i've my object with all properties. My code :

Add post :

```
Template.postListAdmin.events({
  'submit form': (e) => {

    // Prevent default browser form submit
    e.preventDefault();

    let image = $('#js-image-uploaded'),
        draft = $('[name="draft"]'),
        isSmall = false,
        isDrafted = false;

    // If post draft, return true
    if (draft.is(':checked')) isDrafted = true;

    // If post image is small
    // return true for add 'small' classe
    if (image.height() < 80) isSmall = true;

    let post = {
      title: $('[name="title"]').val(),
      image: image.attr('src'),
      isSmall: isSmall,
      description: $('[name="description"]').val(),
      category: $('[name="category"]').val(),
      time: $('[name="time"]').val(),
      dateCreated: dateFormat($('[name="dateCreated"]').val(), 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
      content: $('[name="content"]').val(),
      draft: isDrafted
    };

    Meteor.call('posts.insert', post);

    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#js-post-form')
        .toggleClass('is-hidden')
        .find('input, textarea').val('');
    }, 500);

  }
});
```

Edit post :

```
Template.postEdit.events({
  'submit form': function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    let image = $('#js-image-uploaded'),
        draft = $('[name="draft"]'),
        isSmall = false,
        isDrafted;

    if (draft.is(':checked')) isDrafted = true;
    else isDrafted = false;

    if (image.height() < 80) isSmall = true;

    let post = {
      slug: $('[name="title"]').val(),
      title: $('[name="title"]').val(),
      image: image.attr('src'),
      isSmall: isSmall,
      description: $('[name="description"]').val(),
      category: $('[name="category"]').val(),
      time: $('[name="time"]').val(),
      dateCreated: dateFormat($('[name="dateCreated"]').val(), 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
      dateModified: new Date(),
      content: $('[name="content"]').val(),
      draft: isDrafted
    };

    Meteor.call('posts.edit', this._id, post);

    Router.go('postListAdmin');

  },
});
```

I would like optimize my code and avoid creating my object 'post' 2x.

Do you have any idea how i can optim this ?

Thank you every boby :)

Comment: Either pull the equal parts into a function or nest the edit template inside the admin edit template.

Comment: Have you an example ? I've not really understand :(

Comment: You have got some reading to do. Look at refactoring and read [the Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/). It will teach you a lot. As much as I like the "head first" approach, some things need to be learned by RTFM. In addition, don't change your view with a timeout. Meteor methods have callbacks for this reason.

Comment: One simplification would be to use simple-schema and define all the automatic values there, ex: `dateCreated`, `dateModified`, `draft`. This would also prevent dates being tampered with on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you want to do by defining post without the `let` keyword.

For example:

```
post = {
  title: $('[name="title"]').val(),
  image: image.attr('src'),
  isSmall: isSmall,
  description: $('[name="description"]').val(),
  category: $('[name="category"]').val(),
  time: $('[name="time"]').val(),
  dateCreated: dateFormat($('[name="dateCreated"]').val(), 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
  content: $('[name="content"]').val(),
  draft: isDrafted
};
```

You will have to decide how you want to handle the two instances, though, since they are not exactly the same. Also, moving the variable definition outside of either file might be helpful for organizing your code. You could use a directory on the client named `utils`, and add a file that contains your global variable definitions.

Comment: Hi. I've test to define my let on other file, but the "data" is empty when i submit my form.

Comment: In Meteor, you can set a global variable by declaring it without a `let` or `var` keyword, so just using `post = ` instead of `let post =` or `var post =`.